No content in pytest html report
I'm using python 3.10 and I recently upgraded from pytest 7.3.1 to pytest 8.1.1 and upgraded pytest-html from 3.2.0 to 4.1.1.
After the update, the generated html report for the same test doesn't contain any data. I keep getting what I believe is the template with the green button stating that "There are still running tests. Reload this page to get the latest results!". Clicking on reload does not make a difference. I'm positive that the tests are indeed finished as I can see the logs on stdout.
I've tried inserting dummy data through pytest_html_results_table_row fixture to ensure that the issue is not coming from what I'm inserting and I confirm that I still can't see anything in the report aside from the metadata.

When I downgrade to 4.0.2, I can see data being inserted in the table, but the green button still appears.

I have self-contained-report option active, I don't use --capture or --show-capture options, nor -s.
A bit complicated to provide a test code, it happens even for dummy test, with the example code provided in pytest-html documentation to make the report (pytest-html doc).
Here is the content of my pytest.ini:
[pytest]
minversion = 6.0
addopts = --css=autotest/config/assets/style.css --json=autotest/config/config.json
testpaths = autotest/scenarios
log_cli=true
log_level=INFO
log_format = [%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)8s %(message)s
log_date_format = %H:%M:%S

Any idea?

That green bar is the new function comes with version 4 (as far as I remember), which allow users to analyze/see finished tests while other tests still continue and disappears when all tests are done. So what happens in your case is pytest-html is having problem when your test is finished so the html file is corrupted. Do you use any pytest-html hook in your conftest file? Then you should better focus on that part, It is not related with your test codes.
